# Javascript - window.open not working in IE when calling it through SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am facing an issue while trying to open a drill through report window using Javascript's window.open function. It works fine in Chrome and the new report window pops up when I click on the hyperlink but nothing happens in IE. The parent page is embedded in a web page using IFrame and through go to URL hyperlink it takes to the drill through report.

I am using SSRS2008 R2. The parent report has a hyperlink on one of the columns and in the action I have mentioned javascript to popup drill through report in a new window. I pass a parameter to run the drill through report.

Here's the javascript which I tried using:

="javascript:void(window.open('http://mywebsite.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/AvailableOrdersDrillDownReport&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false&OrderNumber=1234','OrdersDrillDown','innerWidth=860,innerHeight=500','_blank'))"

I also tried using this script: ="javascript:void(window.open('http://mywebsite.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/AvailableOrdersDrillDownReport&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false&OrderNumber=1234','OrdersDrillDown','innerWidth=860,innerHeight=500','_blank'))"

None of these work in IE. However, if I directly paste only the javascript in IE  address bar and try from there, it works. Is this a know problem with IE when using SSRS drill through via javascript? Can this be achieved by any other way if this doesn't work at all?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem, only when using the ReportViewer.aspx control hosted in an iframe (it works fine when using the ReportRenderer extension), and only after a recent set of windows updates to our machines at work.

I got around the problem by adding a parameter on the end of the SSRS URL that we call:

```
&rc:LinkTarget=_self
```

Comment: I have tried &rc:LinkTarget=_self but my SSRS report is saying that "terminator colon is not allowed."